# Modelling the onset of decoherence in a subspace as a transition out of the subspace

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence

http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.3297v1.pdf

I am currently reading papers discussing the Zeno Effect. The linked paper discusses modelling a transition out of a wanted subspace as the onset of decoherence. Thus by frequently projecting back onto the subspace prevents decoherence. I don't quite understand this model. Why does remaining in the subspace mean that coherence must be preserved? Surely environmental effects can decohere the system even if it stays in the subspace. I guess that's what I'm having trouble with, why decoherence is modeled as a transition out of the subspace.

edit

http://www.ba.infn.it/~pascazio/publications/sudarshan_seven_quests.pdf

this paper is shorter and I probably should have attached it initially, section 10 is relevant to my question.

Comment: Just a comment on the paper: in section 1.1 it says "Parmenides and Zeno went to Athens to discuss their ideas with Plato and Aristotle", with no reference given.  This is inconsistent with their biographical information.  It should say that "it is told" that they Parmenides and Zeno met with Socrates, about 450 BC.

Answer (score 0):

The Zeno subspace is a space consists of eigenvectors of the measurement operator P.
As far as I understand, remaining in the subspace doesn't mean coherence must be preserved but completely decoherenced (see page 15 in first paper). Coherent state has interference between survived and not survived states and the interference is removed by measurement.
I'm not sure that my answer is exactly correct but I hope it will be helpful.